# Google play crashing Log

Tags: android

When i am testing my app it's working fine , But when checking on google play its show chasing

Please Suggest me why this error occur and how to solve this type of the error
Google play crashing Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jobDiagnosis.free.MyProfile$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(MyProfile.java:220)
at com.jobDiagnosis.free.MyProfile$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(MyProfile.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

onPostExecute java source code

```
 try{
                if(result!=null)
                {
                // result = result.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
                ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
                Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(result);
                // Parent node is USER
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("USER");
                // fill in the list items from the XML document
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "fname"));// 0
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "lname"));// 1
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "username"));// 2
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "email"));// 3
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "phone1"));// 4
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "phone2"));// 5
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "phone3"));// 6
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "jobmatch"));// 7
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "city"));// 8
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "state"));// 9
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "zip"));// 10
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, ""));// 11
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "month"));// 12
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "day"));// 13
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "year"));// 14
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));// 15
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "company"));// 16
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "education"));// 17
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "optedme"));// 18
                    mylist.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "myid"));// 19


                    myId=mylist.get(19);

                    Log.d("MYLIST", myId);
                //  Toast.makeText(context, "Id"+myId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    txt_Fname.setText(mylist.get(0));
                    txt_Lname.setText(mylist.get(1));
                    if(mylist.get(8).contains("null"))
                    {
                        txt_City.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    txt_City.setText(mylist.get(8));
                    txt_Email.setText(mylist.get(3));
                    if(mylist.get(7).contains("null"))
                    {
                        txt_keyword.setText("customer service");
                    }
                    else
                    txt_keyword.setText(mylist.get(7));
                    txt_Zip.setText(mylist.get(10));
                    if(mylist.get(9).toString().contains("null"))
                    {
                        sp_States.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    sp_States.setText((mylist.get(9).toString()));
                    State = mylist.get(9).toString();

                }

                //str_state=sp_States.getText().toString()+;

                str_city=txt_City.getText().toString()+" ,"+sp_States.getText().toString();
                str_key=txt_keyword.getText().toString();


            //  Toast.makeText(context, "data"+str_city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SharedPreferences  updatepref =getSharedPreferences("LoginActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = updatepref.edit(); 

                 editor1.putString("KEYWORD",txt_keyword.getText().toString().trim());
                 editor1.putString("LOCATION",txt_Zip.getText().toString().trim());
                 editor1.apply();
            }
            }
```

Comment: can you please post onPostExecute() code ?

Comment: Check your line no. 220 in MyProfile java class or paste that code over here.

Comment: @HareshChhelana plese see onPostExecute()  code

Comment: Line NO 220 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("USER");    @amit singh

Comment: try to put try-catch block this line and check which exception will raise.

Comment: @RenuSingh are you sure that you are getting "USER" tag in response?

Comment: @pratik yes USER tag available in XML and when i am testing then its working fine

Comment: @RenuSingh Then when its not working? In which scenario?

Comment: @pratik i think when user go to out side of the app Means Open web browser from app

Comment: @RenuSingh can you please ellaborate your problem in detail, its very much not clear dear.

Comment: @RenuSingh another solution is just cover your code with try...catch so atleast your app will not crashed.

Comment: @RenuSingh have you solved this one or not?

Comment: @pratik No i am testing app, I am not getting any issue, but google play log show cashing

Comment: @RenuSingh can you send me your code?

Answer (score 1):

Since I dont have enough reputation to comment, I am giving my suggestion in Answer.

1) Before publishing the application on google Play, are you using proguard to obfuscate the code?
  -- If yes, try to see if there are any proguard warnings and resolve them before signing the app.

2) Once all the Proguard warnings are solved, sign the app with your keystore and genereate the apk for publisheng, but dont yet publish it on google play, instead copy the signed apk into your device and test the application.

3) If your signed application is working fine, then it must work once you published it.

--- There are some problems when you use proguard, so follow the above process before publishing any app on google play.